# JUnit 5 under Gradle with multiple source sets

Tags: java, gradle, junit, junit5

I've got a project I'm putting together that I want to use JUnit 5 for. I've got this working fine for Unit Tests already.

I do however have multiple test source sets - I've got an additional one for Acceptance Tests. I'm struggling to work out how to get JUnit 5 to run the Unit Tests - defined in src/test - in one task and the Acceptance Tests - defined in the "acceptanceTest" sourceSet and located in "src/acceptance" - in another task.

I have previously got this working with JUnit 4 and Cucumber, but the JUnit 5 plugin doesn't seem to want to work like this.

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
  ext {
    jackson_version = "2.9.0.pr4"
    // IntelliJ needs M4
    junitJupiter_version = "5.0.0-M4"
    junitPlatform_version = "1.0.0-M4"
    kotlin_version = "1.1.3-2"
    slf4j_version = "1.7.25"
    spring_version = "4.3.10.RELEASE"
    springBoot_version = "1.5.4.RELEASE"
    springBootAdmin_version = "1.5.2"

    runAcceptance = System.properties['noAcceptance'] == null
  }

  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath "com.github.ben-manes:gradle-versions-plugin:0.15.0"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:$kotlin_version"
    classpath "org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:$junitPlatform_version"
    classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:$springBoot_version"
  }
}

plugins {
  id "com.github.ben-manes.versions" version "0.15.0"
}

apply plugin: "com.github.ben-manes.versions"
apply plugin: "kotlin"
apply plugin: "kotlin-spring"
apply plugin: "org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin"
apply plugin: "org.springframework.boot"
apply plugin: "war"

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

sourceSets {
  acceptanceTest {
    kotlin {
      compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
      runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
      srcDir file('src/acceptance/kotlin')
    }
    resources.srcDir file('src/acceptance/resources')
  }
}

configurations {
  acceptanceTestCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
  acceptanceTestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}

dependencies {
  compile "com.graphql-java:graphql-java-tools:3.1.3"
  compile "com.graphql-java:graphql-spring-boot-starter:3.5.0"
  compile "com.zaxxer:HikariCP:2.6.3"
  compile("de.codecentric:spring-boot-admin-server:$springBootAdmin_version") {
      exclude group: "junit", module: "junit"
  }
  compile("de.codecentric:spring-boot-admin-server-ui:$springBootAdmin_version") {
      exclude group: "junit", module: "junit"
  }
  compile("de.codecentric:spring-boot-admin-starter-client:$springBootAdmin_version") {
      exclude group: "junit", module: "junit"
  }
  compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
  compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
  compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:$slf4j_version"
  compile "org.springframework:spring-jdbc:$spring_version"
  compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:$springBoot_version"
  compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:$springBoot_version"
  compile "ru.yandex.qatools.embed:postgresql-embedded:2.2"

  runtime "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3"
  runtime "org.jolokia:jolokia-core:1.3.7"
  runtime "org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.5.3"
  runtime "org.postgresql:postgresql:42.1.3"
  runtime "org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:$slf4j_version"
  runtime "org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:$slf4j_version"

  testCompile "com.github.sbrannen:spring-test-junit5:1.0.0.M4"
  testCompile "com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin:1.5.0"
  testCompile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlin_version") {
      exclude group: "junit", module: "junit"
  }
  testCompile "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:$junitJupiter_version"

  testRuntime "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:$junitJupiter_version"

  acceptanceTestCompile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:$springBoot_version"
}

task acceptanceTest(type: Test) {
  testClassesDirs = sourceSets.acceptanceTest.output.classesDirs
  classpath = sourceSets.acceptanceTest.runtimeClasspath
  outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}

if (ext.runAcceptance) {
  check.dependsOn acceptanceTest
}
acceptanceTest.mustRunAfter test

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
  gradleVersion = "4.0"
}
```

Comment: Could you show us the relevant parts of your build.gradle? Also do any of your tests run in Junit5?

Comment: Just added my entire build.gradle to the post. Running "gradle test" will successfully run the unit tests, but not the acceptance tests. I can however run all of them individually from inside IntelliJ. (I will say that I'm very new to Gradle - being a big Maven user until recently - so it might not be the best structured build script!)

Answer (score 5):

Since Gradle 4.6 the gradle Java plugin has [JUnit 5 support](https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/release-notes.html?_ga=2.42865062.2094958155.1519854437-1025556230.1509999788#junit-5-support)

So once you have configured the test source sets, the setup is as simple as follows - for my `test` and `intTest` test tasks I just need to configure this to use JUnit5:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

intTest {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.1.0")
    testRuntime("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.1.0")

}
```

Comment: I get an error: `Could not find method intTest() for arguments...` :(

Answer (score 5):

To refine existing answers, you need to configure *each* of your `Test`-type tasks to include `useJUnitPlatform()`. In your concrete example this would look like

```
task acceptanceTest(type: Test) {
  useJUnitPlatform()
  testClassesDirs = sourceSets.acceptanceTest.output.classesDirs
  classpath = sourceSets.acceptanceTest.runtimeClasspath
  outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}
```

You can also do this centrally via

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: And throw in a `group "Verification"` while you're at it... maybe some `testLogging({...})`.

Answer (score 2):

The JUnit 5 plugin only creates one task - `junitPlatformTest`, and bases it on the `junitPlatform` extension.

If you want to run acceptance tests, or any other type of tests in another source set independently, you'll need to create your own `JavaExec` task, like the plugin does.

See: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/blob/master/junit-platform-gradle-plugin/src/main/groovy/org/junit/platform/gradle/plugin/JUnitPlatformPlugin.groovy#L66

Answer (score 1):

You might want to create a task like this:

```
task e2eTest(
        type: JavaExec,
        description: 'Runs the e2e tests.',
        group: 'Verification'
) {
    dependsOn testClasses
    shouldRunAfter test

    classpath = sourceSets.e2e.runtimeClasspath

    main = 'org.junit.platform.console.ConsoleLauncher'
    args = ['--scan-class-path',
            sourceSets.e2e.output.getClassesDirs().asPath,
            '--reports-dir', "${buildDir}/test-results/junit-e2e"]
}
```