# Gradle SourceSet dependencies in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, build.gradle

I've got a Gradle project with an additional sourceSet - `acceptance`. This contains my acceptance tests, as opposed to just build-time unit and integration tests.

I also have some helper classes in the standard `test` sourceSet that I'd like to share, but that don't belong in the `main` sourceSet.

Currently this works fine in Gradle, but IntelliJ doesn't like it and I'm not sure why.

My `build.gradle` looks like this:

```
buildscript {
  ext {
    jackson_version = "2.9.0.pr4"
    // IntelliJ needs M4
    junitJupiter_version = "5.0.0-M4"
    junitPlatform_version = "1.0.0-M4"
    kotlin_version = "1.1.3-2"
    slf4j_version = "1.7.25"
    spring_version = "4.3.10.RELEASE"
    springBoot_version = "1.5.4.RELEASE"
    springBootAdmin_version = "1.5.2"

    runAcceptance = System.properties['noAcceptance'] == null
  }

  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath "com.github.ben-manes:gradle-versions-plugin:0.15.0"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:$kotlin_version"
    classpath "org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:$junitPlatform_version"
    classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:$springBoot_version"
  }
}

plugins {
  id "com.github.ben-manes.versions" version "0.15.0"
}

apply plugin: "com.github.ben-manes.versions"
apply plugin: "kotlin"
apply plugin: "kotlin-spring"
apply plugin: "org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin"
apply plugin: "org.springframework.boot"
apply plugin: "war"

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

sourceSets {
  acceptance {
    kotlin {
      compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
      runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
      srcDir file('src/acceptance/kotlin')
    }
    resources.srcDir file('src/acceptance/resources')
  }
}

configurations {
  acceptanceCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
  acceptanceRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}

dependencies {
  compile "com.auth0:java-jwt:3.2.0"
  compile "com.graphql-java:graphql-java-tools:3.2.1"
  compile "com.graphql-java:graphql-spring-boot-starter:3.6.0"
  compile "com.zaxxer:HikariCP:2.6.3"
  compile("de.codecentric:spring-boot-admin-server:$springBootAdmin_version") {
      exclude group: "junit", module: "junit"
  }
  compile("de.codecentric:spring-boot-admin-server-ui:$springBootAdmin_version") {
      exclude group: "junit", module: "junit"
  }
  compile("de.codecentric:spring-boot-admin-starter-client:$springBootAdmin_version") {
      exclude group: "junit", module: "junit"
  }
  compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
  compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
  compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:$slf4j_version"
  compile "org.springframework:spring-jdbc:$spring_version"
  compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:$springBoot_version"
  compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:$springBoot_version"
  compile "ru.yandex.qatools.embed:postgresql-embedded:2.2"

  runtime "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3"
  runtime "org.jolokia:jolokia-core:1.3.7"
  runtime "org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.5.3"
  runtime "org.postgresql:postgresql:42.1.3"
  runtime "org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:$slf4j_version"
  runtime "org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:$slf4j_version"

  testCompile "com.github.sbrannen:spring-test-junit5:1.0.0.M4"
  testCompile "com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin:1.5.0"
  testCompile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlin_version") {
      exclude group: "junit", module: "junit"
  }
  testCompile "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:$junitJupiter_version"

  testRuntime "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:$junitJupiter_version"

  acceptanceCompile "commons-jxpath:commons-jxpath:1.3"
  acceptanceCompile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:$springBoot_version"
}

task acceptance(type: Test) {
  testClassesDirs = sourceSets.acceptance.output.classesDirs
  classpath = sourceSets.acceptance.runtimeClasspath
  outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}

if (ext.runAcceptance) {
  check.dependsOn acceptance
}
acceptance.mustRunAfter test

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
  gradleVersion = "4.0"
}
```

IntelliJ can see dependencies from the `main` sourceSet in the `acceptance` one just fine, but refuses to allow me to access the `test` one - even though a command line build works. What am I missing?

Comment: It seems just fine - try to invalidate caches and restart, sometimes intellij needs that ;) `File -> Invalidate Cache`

Comment: No luck :( I'm considering going back to just `main` and `test`, with the acceptance tests all bundled under `test` because of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45297339/junit-5-under-gradle-with-multiple-source-sets, but it's a shame because I really liked keeping them separate.