# Gradle SourceSet IntelliJ vs. Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, intellij-idea, source-sets

I'm indicating a problem, when i import a gradle project, which is originally built with *Eclipse* ,into *IntelliJ*.
In fact the project is a *gradle-project*, but when I import it into IntelliJ the IDE tells me that it deletes (some) duplicate content roots.

I get a balloon - telling me:

> **Duplicate content roots deleted**

the message in the Event-Log is:

> hh:mm[=22:58] Duplicate content roots detected
>
> Path [/Users/.../someProject/someModule] of module [someModuleName] was removed from modules [someModuleName.someSourceSetName]
>
> Also 1 more path was deduplicatetd. See idea log for details

In General it is a *gradle-project*, but I'm not able to run it in IntelliJ.
It builds using *gradle-Wrapper* on the *command-line (./gradlew build)*, but I **would like to build with IntelliJ to improve the usage using (recompile+reload) and other features of the IDE**.

I have the following modules:

- **A** (A is the module i try to build)
- **B** (B is the module, where i want to reuse the sourceSets 'main' AND 'testutils' of module A)

**Module A** - consists of 3 sourceSets (=main, test, testutils):

```
src/main/java
src/test/java
src/testutils/java
```

**Module A** has the dependencies for testutils (consuming 'main'), test (consuming 'main' & 'testutils'), main (production java-src of the module)

And **Module B** where the sourceSet `testutils` of Module **A** is required within the `main` src and the `tests`;
**Module B** - consumes sourceSet 'A/src/main/java' and 'A/src/testutils/java':

So my gradle files are (slightly shortened):

**A/build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'maven'

sourceSets {
    test.java.srcDirs +='src/testutils/java'
    testutils
}

dependencies {
    api project('someOtherProjectA')
    ...

    testImplementation project('someOtherProjectZZ')
    testutilsImplementation sourceSets.test.compileClasspath
}

task testutilsJar(type: Jar) {
    from sourceSets.testutils.output
      appendix 'testutils'
}

configurations {
    testutils
}

artifacts {
    testutils testutilsJar
}

uploadTestutils {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
                configuration = configurations.testutils
                repository(url: mavenPublicRepository) {
                      authentication(userName: repoUsername, password: repoPassword)
                }
        }           
    }
}

publish.dependsOn uploadTestutils
```

**B/build.gradlew:**

```
dependencies {
  api project('someOtherProjectB')

  api "someOtherDependency"
  ...

  testImplementation project('someOtherProjectC')       
  testImplementation project(path: ':A:theNameOfTheModule', configuration: 'testutils')
  ...
  
}
```

My DEV-System-Settings:

```
JDK: 11.0.4
Gradle-Wrapper with Version: gradle-5.5.1
IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1 (Ultimate Edition) - Build #IU-201.6668.121, built on April 8, 2020
    Runtime version: 11.0.6+8-b765.25 x86_64
    VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
    macOS 10.15.4
    Memory: 3987M
    Cores: 16
```

I have already tried using the answers from

- [How do I add a new sourceset to Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581419/how-do-i-add-a-new-sourceset-to-gradle)
- [Gradle SourceSet dependencies in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45357488/gradle-sourceset-dependencies-in-IntelliJ)

I would be very grateful for an advise how I could manage my 'testutils'-SourceSet that it also builds the enclosing project with the embedded IntelliJ-Build:

- Settings (=**Build, Execution, Deployement** > **Build Tools** > **Gradle**)

  - build and run using > 'IntelliJ IDEA' (instead of 'Gradle')
  - run tests using > 'IntelliJ IDEA' (instead of 'Gradle')

Comment: What error do you get in IDE? Do you use `idea` Gradle plugin? Can you provide [sample project](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find a solution for my problem.

The sourceSet is defined in module A and referenced in module B.

The sourceSets of module A:

- main
- testutils (can use main and sees all dependencies of main AND test)
- test (tests main + testutils)

in **module A (build.gradle):**

```
apply plugin: 'maven'

sourceSets {
    testutils
    testutils.compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
    testutils.runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
    test.compileClasspath += sourceSets.testutils.output
    test.runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.testutils.output
}

dependencies {
    api project('someOtherProjectA')
    ...

    testImplementation project('someOtherProjectZZ')
    testutilsImplementation sourceSets.main.compileClasspath
}
...
```

in **module B (build.gradle):**

```
dependencies {
  testImplementation project(path: ':A:theNameOfTheModule', configuration: 'testutils')
  ...
}
```

Module B gets only access to the sourceSet `testutils` of Module A.